# Replace Observation in Col A if Col B is Not Empty, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
      Name      Preferred Name
0     Tyler     None
1     Rachel    None
2     Jason     None
3     Jack      John
4     Peter     None
```

I'd like to overwrite the observation in the Name field with the Preferred Name field if there is a Preferred Name available, to get:

```
      Name      Preferred Name
0     Tyler     None
1     Rachel    None
2     Jason     None
3     John      John
4     Peter     None
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried to create a dictionary from Name:Preferred Name, and then use the dictionary to overwrite, but it brings over all of the blank values in this case.
Is there any way to apply it to only those rows where Preferred Name is populated?

Thank you

Comment: fillna the second column with the first  also should work : `df['Name'] = df['Preferred Name'].fillna(df['Name'])`

Comment: I will try this method as well. I'm still learning python coding basics, so I want to execute various methods so I can learn more about the underlying functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df.loc[df.PreferredName.notna(), 'Name'] = df.PreferredName
```

---

```
print(df)

     Name PreferredName
0   Tyler           NaN
1  Rachel           NaN
2   Jason           NaN
3    John          John
4   Peter           NaN
```